# How to setup a non-Salesforce host or service serves this domain over HTTPS using Salesforce Domains

Tags: community, force.com-sites, custom-domain, mydomain

Hello Everyone right now I have this configuration:

I want to use cloudflare's cdn stuff to serve up my salesforce community or visualforce page faster.

[image]

What goes in the external hostname field? I've gotten many different answers and none of them work.

[image]

I am currently using Cloudflare for the domain and I've setup the CNAME as [domain].0000000000000000000000.live.siteforce.com

Also how do I setup where they say: You must configure your non-Salesforce host or service to forward (proxy) the request to https://recovery.force.com while passing through the originally requested Host HTTP header value. is this apart of the problem?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm trying to do the same thing.